# Windows 2003 Server Blocking .exe files

Tags: windows-server-2003, security

I have built 2 x windows 2003 r2 servers, during the teaming of two nics, the nics would not team correctly due to an issue with the switch I was connected to, only one nic would work, the second was disabled.

Windows went into a high security mode and wouldn't allow me to run or install any exe files.

After the network issue was resolved and i successfully teamed the network cards, but windows still wont allow the installation of .exe's etc.

Troubleshooting as below

1. I've removed the server from the domain and re-added.
2. Tried removing the block notification as suggested below but this ineffective as it effects every .exe file.
3. I've removed Data Execution Protection as suggested below but the problem is the same.

This problem is the same on both servers that suffered this teaming issue, there is a block on all files and an error message with a permissions message appears is attached.

**I think the only option now is to fully rebuild the servers.**

Here is the error message:

Windows cannot access the specified device, path,or file. You may not have the appropriate permissions to access the item.

[image]

Comment: What is the exact text of the error message?

Comment: There's absolutely *nothing* in Windows that could block the execution of files due to network adapter issues. The two things are completely coincidental.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it contains none of the relevant information required to accurately assess the issue, such as an error message or what troubleshooting was performed.  This question may be a better fit on psychicIT.stackexchange.com

Comment: I've updated the original post.

Comment: The servers were rebuilt and the error has not reappeared.

Answer (score 4):

Right click the `.exe`, choose `Properties`. There, you should have a button `Unblock`. Click it, try to execute it again.

This usually happens for files on network drives, or copied from the internet.

Comment: Upvoting your answer.  Heh.  It's been awhile since I was primarily '03.  :D

Comment: Still got some 2k3's around in the testlab, happens occasionally ;)

Comment: This is from anything from my local network or even when i move files over to the local machine.

Comment: Yes, anything from "outside" which was not trusted before

Comment: So how do i unblock this for every exe going forward.

Comment: I don't think you can :) Security... duh!

Answer (score 1):

This is probably [Data Execution Protection](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/875352) and not related to your network cards.  Check your DEP settings in Properties -> Advanced -> Performance Settings -> Data Execution Protection and see if that helps.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this was enabled its now disabled but the problem remains.

Comment: Even when you follow @MichelZ's answer?

Comment: Yes, every exe on the machine is blocked even from the network shares or when it copied to the local drive.